# Springboot @PropertySource with --spring.config.location=/etc/foo/

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I'd like to completely externalize my config files so that every *.properties file is in /etc/foo/.

But I don't want everything in one big application.properties so I split certain parts away into individual *.properties files.

How can I tell @PropertySource that it should resolve the location of the given property file exactly as it would do for its application.properties i.e. search for it in every directly (could be multiple) that I specified with "--spring.config.location"?

My class would ideally look this way:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("dpuProfiles.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("dpu.profiles")
public class DpuProfilesConfiguration {
...
}
```

It does work if I explicitly specify "file:/etc/foo/dpuProfiles.properties".
I couldn't get "${spring.config.location}/dpuProfiles.properties" or similar substitution with EL working. Makes probably no sense either as the variable could contain multiple directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by specify the the config(s) directory in your `-classpath` and point it from classpath to your `@PropertySource`

For your case it will be

```
CLASSPATH=just_added_as_an_example_jar.jar:/etc/foo/
-classpath "$CLASSPATH"
```

But you need to change the `@PropertySource` value as follows

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:dpuProfiles.properties"})
@ConfigurationProperties({"classpath:dpu.profiles"})
```

> Note - The above example is to run from script.

Comment: Using /etc/foo as classpath directory was a good idea.
My @ConfigurationProperites was correct though as it gets the property name prefix and not the filename as parameter.
Additionally I added /etc/foo to my <build><testResources> in pom.xml so that "mvn test" still finds them.